# Cannot call abstract execute Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a Reorder class in my extension, it was extends abstract Reorder at **Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder**

In abstract it have execute method, but when I call it on Reorder class by

```
class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder
{
    public function execute()
    {
        parent::execute();
    }
}
```

It return **404** page without any error. I tried

```
var_dump(123);die();
```

at beginning of execute method of abstract but it doesn't return anything and still return **404** page.

Anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: please share your code?

Comment: Did you configure routes.xml?

Comment: @AmitBera Check my edit

Comment: @RiccardoT of course, it run when I var_dump before parent::execute();

Answer (score 0):

do you have an order id defined in your request?

The execute method calls the load function on the OrderLoader Object which redirects you to noroute if no order id is specified

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/AbstractController/OrderLoader.php#L80

Comment: I don't, but I had var_dump and die() before it call loader. It still return 404